# How to append column to existing file in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file named bt.B.1.log that looks like this:

```
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.37
.
.
.
Compiled procs  =                        1
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.04
.
.
.
Compiled procs  =                        1
.
.
.
```

and so on for 40 records of Time in seconds and Compiled procs (dots represent useless lines).
How do I add a single column with the value of Compiled procs (which is 1) to the result of the following two commands:

- This prints the average of Time in seconds values (thanks to dawg for this one)

  awk -F= '/Time in seconds/ {s+=$2; c++} END {print s/c}' bt.B.1.log > t1avg.dat

Desired output:

```
260.20 1
```

- This prints all of the ocurrences of Time in seconds, but there is a small problem with it; it is printing an extra blank line at the beginning of the list.

  awk 'BEGIN { FS = "Time in seconds =" } ; { printf $2 } {printf " "}' bt.B.1.log > t1.dat

Desired output:

```
260.37 1
260.04
.
.
.
```

In both cases I need the value of Compiled procs to appear only once, preferrably in the first line, and no use of intermediate files.
What I managed to do so far prints all values of Time in seconds with the Compiled procs column appearing in every line and with a strange identation:

```
awk '/seconds/ {printf $5} {printf " "} /procs/ {print $4}' bt.B.1.log > t1.dat
```

Please help!

**UPDATE**

Contents of file bt.B.1.log:

```
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
Start in 16:40:51--25/12/2014


NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.3 -- BT Benchmark 

No input file inputbt.data. Using compiled defaults
Size:  102x 102x 102
Iterations:  200    dt:   0.0003000
Number of active processes:     1

Time step    1
Time step   20
Time step   40
Time step   60
Time step   80
Time step  100
Time step  120
Time step  140
Time step  160
Time step  180
Time step  200
Verification being performed for class B
accuracy setting for epsilon =  0.1000000000000E-07
Comparison of RMS-norms of residual
       1 0.1423359722929E+04 0.1423359722929E+04 0.7507984505732E-14
       2 0.9933052259015E+02 0.9933052259015E+02 0.3147459568137E-14
       3 0.3564602564454E+03 0.3564602564454E+03 0.4783990739472E-14
       4 0.3248544795908E+03 0.3248544795908E+03 0.2309751522921E-13
       5 0.3270754125466E+04 0.3270754125466E+04 0.8481098651866E-14
Comparison of RMS-norms of solution error
       1 0.5296984714094E+02 0.5296984714094E+02 0.2682819657265E-15
       2 0.4463289611567E+01 0.4463289611567E+01 0.1989963674771E-15
       3 0.1312257334221E+02 0.1312257334221E+02 0.4060995034457E-15
       4 0.1200692532356E+02 0.1200692532356E+02 0.2958887128106E-15
       5 0.1245957615104E+03 0.1245957615104E+03 0.2281113665977E-15
Verification Successful


BT Benchmark Completed.
Class           =                        B
Size            =            102x 102x 102
Iterations      =                      200
Time in seconds =                   260.37
Total processes =                        1
Compiled procs  =                        1
Mop/s total     =                  2696.83
Mop/s/process   =                  2696.83
Operation type  =           floating point
Verification    =               SUCCESSFUL
Version         =                      3.3
Compile date    =              25 Dec 2014

Compile options:
   MPIF77       = mpif77
   FLINK        = $(MPIF77)
   FMPI_LIB     = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lo...
   FMPI_INC     = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openm...
   FFLAGS       = -O
   FLINKFLAGS   = -O
   RAND         = (none)


Please send the results of this run to:

NPB Development Team 
Internet: npb@nas.nasa.gov

If email is not available, send this to:

MS T27A-1
NASA Ames Research Center
Moffett Field, CA  94035-1000

Fax: 650-604-3957


Finish in 16:45:14--25/12/2014
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
Start in 16:58:50--25/12/2014


NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.3 -- BT Benchmark 

No input file inputbt.data. Using compiled defaults
Size:  102x 102x 102
Iterations:  200    dt:   0.0003000
Number of active processes:     1

Time step    1
Time step   20
Time step   40
Time step   60
Time step   80
Time step  100
Time step  120
Time step  140
Time step  160
Time step  180
Time step  200
Verification being performed for class B
accuracy setting for epsilon =  0.1000000000000E-07
Comparison of RMS-norms of residual
       1 0.1423359722929E+04 0.1423359722929E+04 0.7507984505732E-14
       2 0.9933052259015E+02 0.9933052259015E+02 0.3147459568137E-14
       3 0.3564602564454E+03 0.3564602564454E+03 0.4783990739472E-14
       4 0.3248544795908E+03 0.3248544795908E+03 0.2309751522921E-13
       5 0.3270754125466E+04 0.3270754125466E+04 0.8481098651866E-14
Comparison of RMS-norms of solution error
       1 0.5296984714094E+02 0.5296984714094E+02 0.2682819657265E-15
       2 0.4463289611567E+01 0.4463289611567E+01 0.1989963674771E-15
       3 0.1312257334221E+02 0.1312257334221E+02 0.4060995034457E-15
       4 0.1200692532356E+02 0.1200692532356E+02 0.2958887128106E-15
       5 0.1245957615104E+03 0.1245957615104E+03 0.2281113665977E-15
Verification Successful


BT Benchmark Completed.
Class           =                        B
Size            =            102x 102x 102
Iterations      =                      200
Time in seconds =                   260.04
Total processes =                        1
Compiled procs  =                        1
Mop/s total     =                  2700.25
Mop/s/process   =                  2700.25
Operation type  =           floating point
Verification    =               SUCCESSFUL
Version         =                      3.3
Compile date    =              25 Dec 2014

Compile options:
   MPIF77       = mpif77
   FLINK        = $(MPIF77)
   FMPI_LIB     = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lo...
   FMPI_INC     = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openm...
   FFLAGS       = -O
   FLINKFLAGS   = -O
   RAND         = (none)


Please send the results of this run to:

NPB Development Team 
Internet: npb@nas.nasa.gov

If email is not available, send this to:

MS T27A-1
NASA Ames Research Center
Moffett Field, CA  94035-1000

Fax: 650-604-3957


Finish in 17:03:12--25/12/2014
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
```

There are 40 entries in the log, but I've provided only 2 for abbreviation purposes.

Comment: A bunch of lines that contain nothing but dots are useless, get rid of them and simply provide some real, testable, input and the associated expected output. Also, don't use the same number for every occurrence of compiled procs, vary it in the input so we can tell where it's coming from when it appears in the output.

Comment: Updated, provided some real data; expected outputs maintained (just ignore the dots on the second one).

Comment: Can you just clean it up to show the stuff that we actually need to see? We don't need stuff that you tell us to ignore and we don't need to see stuff that was there before you updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the first issue, replace:

```
awk -F= '/Time in seconds/ {s+=$2; c++} END {print s/c}' bt.B.1.log > t1avg.dat
```

with:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ \t]*=[ \t]*" }  /Time in seconds/ { s += $2; c++ } /Compiled procs/ { if (! CP) CP = $2 } END { print s/c, CP }' bt.B.1.log >t1avg.dat
```

A potential minor issue is that `260.205 1` might be output but the question does not address this as a weakness of the given script.  Rounding with something like `printf "%.2f %s\n", s/c, CP` gives `260.21 1` though.  To truncate the extra digit, use something like `printf "%.2f %s\n", int (s/c * 100) / 100, CP`.

To fix the second issue, replace:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "Time in seconds =" } ; { printf $2 } {printf " "}' bt.B.1.log > t1.dat
```

with:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ \t]*[=][ \t]" }  /Time in seconds/ { printf "%s", $2 } /Compiled procs/ { if (CP) { printf "\n" } else { CP = $2; printf " %s\n", $2 } }' bt.B.1.log > t1.dat
```

BTW, the "strange indentation" is a result of failing to output a newline when using `printf` and failing to filter unwanted input lines from processing.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, but I had to remove the 4 occurrences of hat (^) before. With the hats, for the first issue, I got a 'division by zero attempted' error message and for the second, it wasn't outputting anything. Removing the hats has solved the problems.

Comment: I edited out the "^" from the regular expressions in the answer.